# How should I update the data in database to my users?

Tags: android

I'm working on an app that needs to have it's data updated once a week. There are probably ways to do this by scheduling the app to wake up on a specific day and time and then do the work. Could I fetch the data myself, insert into the database and create an update for the app so that users would then have this new data when they install the update?

Answer (score 0):

That is not a good idea because you are forcing user to download the app again and again. This is very bad user experience and is not recommended. Scheduling for sync data is recommended and user will not be notify about downloading data and consuming internet.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the android WorkManager.
The WorkManager API makes it easy to specify deferrable, asynchronous tasks and when they should run. These APIs let you create a task and hand it off to WorkManager to run immediately or at an appropriate time.

[Android WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/)

Or you can use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) in combination with broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 0):

I think AlarmManager or JobScheduler will help you with this task. Both are Android features, but JobScheduler is available in Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher. Basically, this will schedule a task to be executed after a certain period. In my opinion, the best approach here is JobScheduler. Here is an example of implementation:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html

Example using AlarmManager:

http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/06/android-alarm-manager-to-start-service.html